# Struggling with boolean flag in Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm attempting to create a script that fires when a checkbox is checked, and when it is unchecked and rechecked. When it's initially checked, it's supposed to output the current date, and the user's email in columns N and O. When it's unchecked, nothing is supposed to happen, and when it is rechecked, only the users email should be outputted in column P.

What's currently happening when I run my script is columns N and O are inputted with the date and email, and column P is also getting an email input simultaneously. Also, when you attempt to delete the email in column P it immediately shows up 3 columns over.

I've attempted reorganizing the boolean flags however it has been to no avail. If anyone recognizes any errors in my code, I would greatly appreciate any input.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var uncheck = "FALSE";
  var recheck = "FALSE";
  const range = e.range;
  range.setNote(email + new Date());

  if (sh.getName() == "Form Responses 1", range.columnStart == 13 && e.value == "TRUE") { //If checkbox is checked
    e.range.offset(0, 1, 1, 2).setValues([
      [new Date(), email]]);
    if (uncheck == "TRUE") {
      recheck = "TRUE";
    }
  }
  else if (sh.getName() == "Form Responses 1", range.columnStart == 13 && e.value == "FALSE") { //If checkbox is unchecked
    uncheck = "TRUE";
    //e.range.offset(0, 2, 1, 1).setValues([[email]]);
  }

  if (uncheck && recheck) { //If uncheck and recheck are true
    //sh.getName() == "Form Responses 1", range.columnStart == 13 && e.value == "TRUE"
    e.range.offset(0, 3, 1, 1).setValues([[email]]); //supposed to output email in column P
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure they are set correctly as string `"TRUE"`? Try using proper javaScript `true`?

Comment: You also might find it easier to interact with the true range variable (`range` in your code). Use that to get value (i.e. `range.getValue()`? Also the first condition in your if statement of getting sheet name is always going to be true since it's set that way above.

Comment: Also what is `columnStart`? Are you sure that's getting the first (and last) column of range?

Comment: e.range.columnStart is part of the onEdit event object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the use of flags is not helping. I think that the simplest alternative is to read the values of the row of the edited range to determine the "check" / "recheck" status.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  e.range.setNote(email + new Date());

  if (sh.getName() == "Form Responses 1" && e.range.columnStart == 13){
    // Get cells from the same row, columns N and O
    const range = e.range.offset(0, 1, 1, 2);
    const values = range.getValues().flat()
    if(e.value == "TRUE"){
      if(values.every(v => v == '')) { // If N and O are empty then the state is checked
      range.setValues([[new Date(), email]]);
      } else {  // If N or O aren't empty then the state is rechecked
        // Write the email to same row, first empty cell to the right
        e.range.offset(0, 0, 1, sh.getLastColumn() - 12 ).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).offset(0,1).setValue(email);
      }
    } else if (e.value == "FALSE") {
    // do nothing
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works how I intended it to. Would it be possible to keep adding additional emails in the next columns if the checkbox is repeatedly unchecked and rechecked? I imagine it would be some sort of i=i++ type of function.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. There are many ways to do it, one option is to use [Range.getNextDataCell(direction)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnextdatacelldirection)

Comment: Answer updated (not tested)

Comment: Thank you, I will test that out to see what I can do. I appreciate your help throughout this learning process!

Comment: @cogre applied a fix (NEXT should be uppercase, and modified the parameters of the relate offset.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  e.range.setNote(email + new Date());
  if (sh.getName() == "Form Responses 1", e.range.columnStart == 13 && e.value == "TRUE") { 
    e.range.offset(0, 1, 1, 2).setValues([[new Date(), email]]);
  }
  else if (sh.getName() == "Form Responses 1" && e.range.columnStart == 13 && e.value == "FALSE") { 
    e.range.offset(0, 2).setValue(email);
  }
}
```

It wasn't clear to me yesterday when you asked this question and it's still not  but let's try starting here.  Tell me what's working and what's not

Comment: Thanks for the response. What you wrote does the initial job correctly, as it inputs the date and email in columns N and O. What it should do next is input the email again in columns P, Q, R... when the checkbox is unchecked then checked again.